# How to make flowfiles received from ListFile processor wait until processing of one particular flowfile among them (if present) is completed?

Tags: apache-nifi, wait, notify

Suppose I've a directory which contains multiple files. I want to list the directory, fetch all files and process them. But if there is a flowfile with a particular filename (e.g., file.txt) then I want to process this flowfile first before processing any other one. Please note I can't list the directory again due to my use case limitations. It has to be in a single flow.

Comment: Well you're using NiFi to handle a batch process, which isn't really what its designed for, but is still possible. You could have a Merge that waits for X amount of time to add all file names to a single flow file. Then the simplest way is probably to have a script that through the names, matches on 'file.txt' and sends that out as its own flow file first, then sends out the others - going in to a Fetch. You'd need to run it all on the primary node with 1 threads on all processors to ensure it keeps the order. This is not very good practise though.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something similar to below flow. Use `Wait-Notify` to implement gate like mechanism. But I think, to work this as expected you need to set `Run Schedule` for ListFile and the execution interval should be greater than expiration duration of `Wait` processor so that if a specific file is not present in the list of that execution attempt still those files will be processed before next execution of ListFile and won't be stuck at `Wait` processor queue!

[image: flow]